# Read the response from POST request in Angular 7

Tags: angular, post

Hi I have an Angular 8  app  that posts data to API (REST in PHP). I am able to post the data to the server and create a new record using the code below.

**Question:** I would like to read the response from the API method. For example I have logic in the API that checks if the record is already created or not. If the account exists then the API Returns

```
["MSG":"DUPLICATE_FOUND","STATUS":200]
```

Otherwise it returns

```
["MSG":"SUCCESS","STATUS":200]
```

I would like to read property MSG after the subscribe and then apply the logic (i.e. show the error message, or other action). But when I do console.log(data) it is returned null.

**signup component:**

```
this.userService.addNewUser(user).subscribe(
(data) => {
   console.log(data);
},
error => console.log(error)
```

**user.service.ts**

```
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type':  'application/json'
})
};

addNewUser (user): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post<any>(endpoint + 'createNewUser', user, httpOptions).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError<any>())
);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are u seeing the expected response in `Network` tab of dev tool ? Can u share the screenshot ??

Comment: What was logged by `console.log(data);`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your response is not in the correct format. What Angular is expecting is a valid JSON response, which in your case you get by replacing the square brackets `[]` by curly brackets `{}`, like this:

**Before**

`["MSG": "DUPLICATE_FOUND", "STATUS": 200]`

**After**

`{"MSG": "DUPLICATE_FOUND", "STATUS": 200}`

You can use some online software to validate your JSON in case of doubt, I like this [one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).